# Open a local file with open-uri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, open-uri

I am doing data scraping with Ruby and Nokogiri. Is it possible to download and parse a local file in my computer?

I have:

```
require 'open-uri'

url = "file:///home/nav/Desktop/Scraping/scrap1.html"
```

It gives error as:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - file:\home/nav/Desktop/Scraping/scrap1.html
```

Comment: Not possible.  All your code does is require 'open-uri', then assign a string to a variable.

Comment: Why use OpenURI to open a file when you can use `open` by itself?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to parse a local file with Nokogiri you can do it like this.

```
file = File.read('/home/nav/Desktop/Scraping/scrap1.html')
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(file)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you open a local file in a browser, the URL in the address bar is displayed as:

```
file:///Users/7stud/Desktop/accounts.txt
```

But that doesn't mean you use that format in a Ruby script.  Your Ruby script doesn't send the file name to a browser and then ask the browser to retrieve the file.  Your Ruby script searches your file system directly.

The same is true for URLs: your Ruby script doesn't ask your browser to go retrieve a page from the internet, Ruby retrieves the page itself by sending a request using your system's network interface.  After all, a browser and a Ruby program are both just computer programs.  What your browser can do over a network, a Ruby program can do, too.

This works for me:

```
require 'open-uri'

text = open('./data.txt').read
puts text
```

You have to get your path right, though.  The only reason I can think of to use `open()` is if you had an array of filenames and URLs mixed together.  If that isn't your situation, see new2code's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it as according to the documentation.

```
    f = File.open("//home/nav/Desktop/Scraping/scrap1.html")
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
    f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of Mechanize and save the file locally, then parse it with Nokogiri like so:

```
# Save the file
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download
current_url = 'http://www.example.com'
file = agent.get(current_url)
file.save!("#{Rails.root}/tmp/")

# Read the file
page = Nokogiri::HTML::Reader(File.open(file))
```

Hope that helps!